# Storing DB connections in resource variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on grid library using Hibernate and Spring MVC to read data from DB. I want to store the DB connections in system variable. What I made is making file called `database.properties` and writing the code that reads from the file which is"

```html
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava"/>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
 
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  id="jspViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
  id="dataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
  <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
  <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
  <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
  id="sessionFactory">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Employee</value>
    <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Department</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
  id="hibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>
```

How to use system variables? I read on the internet but still can't find any relevant.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? It is unclear to me what you mean with *store the DB connections into system variable*... To me that doesn't even make sense...

Comment: properties defined in database.properties are not system variables

Comment: @niilzon so i want to store it in system variables

Comment: @M.Deinum i am asking about how to inject system variables in xml ?\

Comment: Please post your database.properties

Comment: Then store it in system variables, remove the `location` tag from `<context:property-placeholder />` and restart your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve. I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<!-- In bean definition-->
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="#{ systemProperties['database.driver'] }"></property>
    <property name="url"  value="#{systemProperties['database.url'] }"></property>
    <property name="username"  value="#{ systemProperties['database.username'] }"></property>
    <property name="password" value= value="#{ systemProperties['database.password'] }"></property></bean>
```

And you can declare the `properties` in the `boxes(Unix/Windows)` where you want to deploy your application.

Comment: can you give me example for this ?? may be links ?

Comment: You don't need that... Just use `${database.driver}` create a system property or environment property with that name and it will be used. No need to resort to SpEL.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: it gives me access denied to DB

Comment: Then you might be having DB access issue or Check for properties if those are getting populated successfully.(Spelling mistakes killed me few times). Also verify if you have system variable defined.

Comment: so where to save the database.properties ?? i am using windows

Comment: set in your env variables which comes under advance settings.